# Notification comes while using app

Tags: ios, swift

When I am using my app, and I pull down the status bar, and a notification comes, I don't see the notification and my code for notification which is present in didRecieveRemoteNotification gets executed without me clicking it.

Comment: than you definitely receive remote notification from your backend server, isn't it?

Comment: Which is exactly how it is supposed to behave. If your app is in the foreground the notification does not get delivered to the notification center.

Comment: Yeah, but some apps do not behave this way. Is there a way to detect that given the application state is ACTIVE, and notification bar is pulled down?